# How to make a list of widgets mutate state based on activity on any one widget?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a GridView Widget which has a list of Custom Buttons. I want to freeze/disable all the remaining buttons in the list if one of the button in the list is clicked.

How can this be done? I had some ideas around perhaps making a Stateful List Widget that holds the state of whats clicked. But i do not know how to mutate that state. Or broadcast it to all the other objects to manipulate its state. Some guidance would be helpful.

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final title = 'Grid List';

    return MaterialApp(
      title: title,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(title),
        ),
        body: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Center(
              child: Container(
                height: 120.0,
                width: 120.0,
                color: Colors.blue[50],
                child: Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.topRight,
                  child: FlutterLogo(
                    size: 60,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            new Expanded(
                child: GridView.count(
                  // shrinkWrap: false,
                  // Create a grid with 2 columns. If you change the scrollDirection to
                  // horizontal, this produces 2 rows.
                  childAspectRatio: 1.2,
                  crossAxisCount: 2,
                  // Generate 100 widgets that display their index in the List.
                  children: <Center> [
                    Center(child: Option("Option 1")),
                    Center(child: Option("Option 2")),
                    Center(child: Option("Option 3")),
                    Center(child: Option("Option 4"))
                  ],
                )
            )
          ],
        ),
    ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You can create a [parallel list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_array) of booleans as a property in the `State` of your `StatefulWidget`, where each element tells if its respective custom button is enabled or disabled. Since `GridView.builder` provides an index, you can use it to check if it's enabled or disabled. When a button is selected, just update the state (using `setState`) setting to false all but the selected button index. I don't know what you've tried so I can't help you with more code.

Answer (score 0):

You should employ a state management solution such as riverpod ([pub.dev](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_riverpod)) ([docs](https://riverpod.dev/)).

This isn't a scalable example but should be enough to get you started.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';

final disabledButtonsProvider = StateProvider<List<bool>>((_) => List.generate(4, (_) => false));

class ButtonGrid extends ConsumerWidget {
  const ButtonGrid({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, ScopedReader watch) {
    final disabledButtons = watch(disabledButtonsProvider).state;

    return Scaffold(
      body: GridView.count(
        crossAxisCount: 2,
        children: List.generate(
          4,
          (index) => ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: disabledButtons[index]
                ? null
                : () => context.read(disabledButtonsProvider).state =
                    List.generate(4, (i) => i != index),
            child: Text(index.toString()),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: @PranavSharma The code you added doesn't really add anything of substance to the question. Have you tried running the code from my answer?